# How to use packages installed by quicklisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, package, sbcl, quicklisp

I've installed the CL-PNG package using quicklisp.

```
(ql:quicklisp 'png)
```

Now I want to define my own package which depends on the CL-PNG package. Like so:

```
(defpackage :FOO
  (:use :CL :PNG)
  (:export :BAR))
```

When compiling it I get this error:

```
The name "PNG" does not designate any package.
   [Condition of type SB-KERNEL:SIMPLE-PACKAGE-ERROR]
```

It seems that I have to call `(require :PNG)` on the REPL before compiling my package.

What do I have to do to make the CL-PNG package available for the compiler without manually call `require` on the REPL?

UPDATE: I'm using SBCL.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You confuse two separate notions: a `system` and a `package`. A `package` is defined by Common Lisp standard and it's a collection of symbols, a way to control their visibility and usage. A `system` is not defined by the standard, it's a notion introduced by `ASDF`, which is a collection of metadata to manage files inter-dependencies in a single project in order to be able to properly compile and load it. `Quicklisp` is built on top of `ASDF` to provide a way to distribute projects, described in the form of `ASDF system`s.

So when you install (`quickload`) a `system`, called `PNG`, this doesn't mean, that this system has a package, called `PNG`. Does the system define any packages (usually it defines one, or even several of them) and how they are called is at the discretion of its author. Most of the projects will have `package.lisp` or `packages.lisp` files, where their `package`s are defined.

But in the case of `CL-PNG` system you're loading, it actually defines the package `PNG`, and it should be available in the running process after you `quickload` it. But you should somehow load it every time you start your Lisp system. `ASDF` provides a means to define a dependency on `CL-PNG` system, so that you can just load only **your own** `system`, and all of the `system`s it depends on will be loaded automatically, making available all `package`s you want to use.

Comment: Can you go into detail about how ASDF provides this? What syntax is necessary?

Comment: Look at the file with `.asd` extension. In more detail the syntax is described here: http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#The-defsystem-grammar

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: For a quick way to get started with ASDF, see [`quickproject`](http://xach.livejournal.com/269028.html). To make the new project available to Quicklisp, put the new project in the `local-projects` directory of your quicklisp distribution (see http://blog.quicklisp.org/2011/11/november-quicklisp-updates.html).